# Switching from MS-Access to Oracle

Tags: oracle, ms-access, oracle-sqldeveloper

Apologies beforehand if I've been an unlucky searcher, but I feel like I'm either using the wrong keywords or there is nothing to find on the subject.

A colleague of mine has been using MS Access for decades and has no experience with other SQL tools. Most of the systems in our organisation are built on Oracle databases (and in quantities too large for MS Access), so data integration is often complex for him. To facilitate things, he will be moving his data sources to one of the Oracle servers, and will be able to access that data with Oracle SQL Developer.

All I'm able to find on the internet is how to migrate data but I'm looking for functionality differences from the perspective of a data analyst or a reporting developer, who works with preparated data.

I tried explaining it in simple terms, such as: "there are tables here as well", or "Oracle views are like Access queries", but there's a lot of ground to cover and I'm looking for some handles.

Do any of you know of a good source to read on this subject? Books, videos, articles, websites, anything. If at all possible, it should be in terms familiar to an MS Access user.

Comment: unfortunately for you this will probably be closed. But if he's being doing SQL for decades he should have no problem moving. There is a learning curve but the concepts of getting data out of a data structure in some very  similar SQL variant are very close. The syntax will be slightly different but, meh, the compiler will tell him when it's wrong. If he we doing administration that'd be a totally different story.

Comment: Have you considered the option of moving the *data* to Oracle but keeping your colleague's (presumably ad-hoc) querying and reporting in Access using ODBC linked tables into the Oracle database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not make it clear what developer tools you plan to replace Access with. Remember Access has two parts. The database part (the data engine). The data engine allows you to build tables, and execute SQL queries to retrieve data. This is also what the Oracle database allows you to accomplish.

Then there is the developer part. That is the part that lets you build forms (to edit data) and that of reports. This part is NOT part of the database engine (for Access or oracle).

So the differences in the database engine are NOT that important here, but MOST important is what tools you plan to build the reports and forms to edit data with?

You can most certainly continue to develop your software using Access. So Access has a VBA programming system, has the ability to develop forms, and also that of reports. However the database engine and table can be form the Oracle database.

So your question shows much confusing here since you not making any distinction between the developer tools (Access), and the database system you choose to WORK WITH Access. Access is a developer tool, much like VB6, c++, vb.net etc. It allows you to build reports and write code and build a user interface. A database system such as ACE, or Oracle or SQL server has no such ability.

The Access database engine (used to be called JET and is now called ACE) is a separate issue.

So a developer writing some software in say vb.net can choose to use the Oracle database system or can use the Access database engine called ACE.

It not clear if you plan to continue to use the Access development system, and then choose an appropriate database system such as SQL Server, MySQL or in your case Oracle as the database engine to work with Access.

If you plan to not use the Access development system to build reports and forms and write code, then you have to share with everyone here what tool(s) you plan to use. Since it sounds like the user is being dictated that they MUST use Oracle as the database system, then it likely that what developer tools such as vb.net, C++ or perhaps MS Access is also going to be forced upon the user.

Until such time you expand on what developer tools which are SEPARATE ISSUE from the database system is shared here, then any real answer is sheer speculation and a waste of our time.

So keep in mind that the Access databases engine, or SQL server, or Oracle or MySQL are database engines. AFTER you choose the database engine/system, you can then write code + forms in something like:

```
Vb.net
MS Access
Asp.net
Etc. etc. etc .etc
```

You also choose such systems as SQL reporting services, or whatever oracle has these days.

So if you crystal reports with ACE (the Access database engine), or you use crystal reports with SQL server or Oracle, then the feature set in crystal reports is VERY MUCH THE SAME in all cases.

And you might use MS Access reports with Oracle or SQL server or often the ACE (the default database engine for Access).

The user can continue to use Access as the user “interface” developer tool, and the data can be in any industry database engine that supports ODBC. The database system does not have nor include the user interface and reporting tools.

You not shared what reporting and development tools you plan to use with Oracle. As to what tool, well that like asking what kind of car to drive or what software development system should one choose. We don’t even know if the user has a choice. If they have a choice then they can continue to use Access and you have no need for a question here!

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate response! I'm not sure anymore what my question was, and which part of your text was the answer I needed, but it's led to a full understanding on my part of what is to be done with the situation I described.